# Model comparison between glm (with Firth correction), random Forest, penalised SVM

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, modeling, roc

I am currently developing three models to classify features of gene sites.

I was using glm (with Firth correction), random Forest and SVM to build the models and I used forward and backward selection for glm (`forward` and `backward` functions from `logistf`), selection using the oob error (with the function `varSelRF` from the package `varSelRF`) and the function `svm.fs` from the package `penalizedSVM` to select variables for the models.

I used cross-validation to validate the model building of training data. I generated ROC curves of the performance on the test data as I want to use ROC as a goodness-of-fit measure.

Now my question: In terms of the best (i.e. best predictive accuracy) model, is it enough to compare the AUC of each ROC curve and choose the model with the highest AUC as the best model?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: That depends entirely what *best* means in your context.

Comment: Sure, if I want to have best predictive accuracy...?

Answer (score 6):

Its a very big & open question on which metrics are best to use to access classifier performance. This paper did a great job comparing them:

Caruana, Rich, and Alexandru Niculescu-Mizil. "Data mining in metric space: an empirical analysis of supervised learning performance criteria." Proceedings of the tenth ACM SIGKDD international conference on Knowledge discovery and data mining. ACM, 2004.

They actually concluded that AUC is one of the best metrics to use - however, its far from foolproof since some methods do better with one metric than another. For example, I'd suspect SVM & RF will do very well with AUC, but GLM might do much better with a probability-based metric such as cross-entropy.

tl;dr: no one will criticize you for using AUC, but know that this metric will still be biased towards some methods over others since there is no 'perfect' metric.

Comment: Thanks! I will vote your answer up, as soon as I have a reputation of 15.

Comment: I don't see any reason to assume that GLMs perform relatively bad in AUROC compared to other metrics.

Comment: @MarcClaesen sorry if my wording was unclear. There is no reason to assume GLMs will do good or bad w/ ROCs - but there is a reason to think that it will be the best method to optimize cross-entropy, since that is what it was designed to do!